# Advantage of using JAX-RS 2.0 with CDI/Weld instead of Guice?

Tags: java, jax-rs, guice, cdi, weld

One goal of JAX-RS 2.0 was to integerate CDI and substitute the old `@Context` with the common `@Inject` injection. But if I look at the [JSR 339](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=339) this is not mentioned. So what is actually the CDI integration? Would there be any advantage of using JAX-RS with CDI instead of Google Guice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Context` is still the official way of doing injection in JAX-RS 2.0. The specification does however state that an implementation MAY make use of `@Inject` alongside `@Context` (from section 10.2.5 of JAX-RS 2.0 EDR 3):

> Implementations MUST NOT require use of `@Inject` or `@Resource` to
>   trigger injection of JAX-RS annotated ﬁelds or properties.
>   Implementations MAY support such usage but SHOULD warn users about
>   non-portability.

Therefore it is not certain that all implementations of JAX-RS 2.0 supports `@Inject`, and incompatibility might arise if one wants to change JAX-RS 2.0 implementation.

I did a little research and it seems Jersey 2.0 just got support for `@Inject` at least.

I guess the advantage in using `@Inject` instead of `@Context` is that it is more consistent alongside all the `@Inject`'s of non JAX-RS resources one would have in a JAX-RS web-service.